# Can't update field in existing document in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to add a field in to an existing document with pymongo.

here is my code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client['profiles']
collection = db['collection']


def createFields():
    collection.update({'_id' : '547f21f450c19fca35de53cd'}, {'$set': {'new_field':1}})

createFields()
```

when I enter the following in to the mongoDB interpreter

```
>use profiles
>db.collection.find()
```

I can see that there have not been any fields added to the specified document.

Comment: does `collection.find({'_id' : '547f21f450c19fca35de53cd'})` return the document?

Answer (score 1):

An _id field is most commonly of type ObjectId() which is a twelve byte value, rather than a 24-byte string as you are providing here.

You must use the correct type in order to match the document.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `db` before your script

Just try this, it works fine for me

### In Mongo CLI

```
> use profiles
> db.collection.insertOne({'_id': '547f21f450c19fca35de53cd'})
> db.collection.find()
{ "_id" : "547f21f450c19fca35de53cd" }
```

### Python Script -> test.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client['profiles']
collection = db['collection']

def createFields():
    db.collection.update({'_id' : '547f21f450c19fca35de53cd'}, {'$set': {'new_field':-881}})

createFields()
```

### Command Line

```
> python test.py
```

### Mongo CLI

```
> use profiles
> db.collection.find()
> { "_id" : "547f21f450c19fca35de53cd", "new_field" : -881 }
```

> For pymongo, use `update_one` or `update_many` instead of `update`